# Background-size cover/center not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to center the background image to the div using `background-size: cover` and `background-size: contain`, but it does not work. I need to display background images inside HTML tags and use background-size in the css file, this is the code:

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.main{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #A6A6A6;
}
.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
.card div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
.card .front {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-image:url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/Syntaxxx/background-gold-bokeh.jpg);">
<div class="main">
  <section class="container">
      <div class="card">
          <div class="front" style="background-image: url('http://www.mobygames.com/images/covers/l/403626-injustice-2-playstation-4-front-cover.png');">
          </div>
          <div class="back">1</div>
      </div>
  </section>
  <section class="container">
      <div class="card">
          <div class="front" style="background-image: url('http://www.mobygames.com/images/covers/l/403651-the-surge-playstation-4-front-cover.jpg');">
          </div>
          <div class="back">2</div>
      </div>
  </section>
</div>
          
</body>
```

Comment: on `.card .front` add `background-position: center center;` Hope that is what you meant, otherwise I'll need more info :)

Comment: `background-position: center center;` fixes your issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `.card .front` has a style of `background-repeat` which you've given too many properties to.

the `center center` needs to be given to `background-position`

```
.card .front {
     background-position: center center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
 }
```

With CSS and most other dimensions you use X then Y then Z (No Z apart from Z-index)

Background-size will enlarge the image until the entire div is full.

What you're looking for is `background-size: contain`. This will display the full image in any container. then add the `center center`

```
.card .front {
    background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/Syntaxxx/background-gold-bokeh.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
 }
```

Comment: Ans whats the difference between put 1 center and put 2 center in background-position?

Comment: One center is for horizontal and another for vertical align. If you write only 1 center it will be added as horizontal and vertical

Comment: But the image is still a bit bigger than showed, why is that? I need to see full image without cutting

Comment: Still doesnt cover .card size, I have updated my question

Comment: Please explain to me how the image will resize and still display the full image in a small div at the same time. I might not fully understand what you need but what it sounds like isn't possible.

Comment: you can `center x` where x is either of the following: `top, bottom, left, right`. play around. That might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple fix, you need to specify `background-position: center;`. This will ensure your background images center itself.

```
.card .front {
    background-position: center;
｝
```

Comment: Ans whats the difference between put 1 center and put 2 center in background-position?

Comment: It is just a shorthand `background-position: x y;`. The first value will be the x-position position and second would be y-position. If only the first provided the the value will be apply to both x & y positions.

Comment: But the image is still a bit bigger than showed, why is that? I need to see full image without cutting

Comment: The reason is because you are using `background-size:contain`, this will squeeze the background image without cutting but the downside is the image porportion need to be the same as your original background image, if not you will get the extra space. Since your backgrounds are squares try setting `width: 260px; height: 260px;` this will avoid white space

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you well, but have you tried background-position: 50%; ?

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.main{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #A6A6A6;
}
.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.card div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
.card .front {
    background-repeat: no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-image:url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/Syntaxxx/background-gold-bokeh.jpg);">
<div class="main">
  <section class="container">
      <div class="card">
          <div class="front" style="background-image: url('http://www.mobygames.com/images/covers/l/403626-injustice-2-playstation-4-front-cover.png');">
          </div>
          <div class="back">1</div>
      </div>
  </section>
  <section class="container">
      <div class="card">
          <div class="front" style="background-image: url('http://www.mobygames.com/images/covers/l/403651-the-surge-playstation-4-front-cover.jpg');">
          </div>
          <div class="back">2</div>
      </div>
  </section>
</div>
          
</body>
```